# Scala REPL not printing Range

Tags: scala, range, read-eval-print-loop

When I try to print a `Range` in Scala REPL, how come it doesn't give me the list of numbers.

It displays `Range(0 to 10)` instead of printing  `Range(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`.

[Scala REPL range printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUkUV.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the `toString` function for Range has changed in Scala `2.12`.

Testing with `2.12.0`:

```
scala> (1 to 10)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 10
```

Testing with `2.11.8`:

```
scala> (0 to 10)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

[Source code for 2.12](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L398-L404):

```
override def toString = {
  val preposition = if (isInclusive) "to" else "until"
  val stepped = if (step == 1) "" else s" by $step"
  val prefix = if (isEmpty) "empty " else if (!isExact) "inexact " else ""
  s"${prefix}Range $start $preposition $end$stepped"
}
```

[Source code for 2.11](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L387-L391):

```
override def toString() = {
  val endStr =
    if (numRangeElements > Range.MAX_PRINT || (!isEmpty && numRangeElements < 0)) ", ... )" else ")"
    take(Range.MAX_PRINT).mkString("Range(", ", ", endStr)
}
```

---

Comment: But it used to show the numbers, no? Did that change?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the question

Comment: Yeah looks like it's changed since 2.12. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution, when you're lost with the bounds of your `Range` and want to inspect its actual individual elements, consists in transforming it as a `List`:

```
scala> (0 until 10)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range 0 until 10
scala> (0 until 10).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```